# Cannot import Bluetooth in Python 3 (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, bluetooth, pybluez

I reinstalled PyBluez some weeks ago since I couldn't get basic functions to work. Now I can't even import it to Python 3.

```
import bluetooth
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import bluetooth
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/bluetooth/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
from .osx import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/bluetooth/osx.py", line 1, in <module>
import lightblue
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightblue/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
from _lightblue import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lightblue'
```

I was not able to install pybluez via pip/pip3, however I was able to install it by downloading the Github project. I have tried to update it, all suggestions I could find on matter online and much more.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closed OS X import issue #108 on GitHub: http://github.com/karulis/pybluez/issues/108

It's actually quite an old issue. What version are you on? El Captain?

One thing the author suggested you might do is remove your current installation and install the GitHub repo using pip:

```
git clone https://github.com/karulis/pybluez.git
pip install -e pybluez
```

That seemed to get the import working for the OP of the GitHub issue, but there were still some bugs due to limited support of OS X. You can read more about the bugs and troubleshooting on GitHub.

Comment: I'm on Sierra 10.12.6. When I tried to install it with your commands I instead get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import bluetooth
  File "/Users/carlbratt/pybluez/build/lib/bluetooth/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .osx import *
  File "/Users/carlbratt/pybluez/build/lib/bluetooth/osx.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lightblue
  ...... and so on.

Comment: @CarlBratt yes that's actually what happened in that thread. I mean I can repeat it all here for you but you really might want to go read it and try the follow up suggestions from the author. When I said that got the import problem to go away but there were still bugs due to it being unsupported on OS X this is what I meant. I think if you follow the comments in that thread you will get it to work half way but it's not going to work fully on OS X unless they've made recent improvements, which it doesn't sound like. You could always run a Linux VM. If you love me you'll upvote / accept :)