# Some issues on installing modules with PyCharm

Tags: python, module, installation, pycharm, pybluez

**With Mac 10.13.2,PyCharm 2017.3(community edition),Python 3.6.4:**

I've been searching high and low but with no luck as whatever I tried didn't work.I have installed `Python 3.6` and `PyCharm` with a success,but it was driving me crazy when I installed the module`time`,`PyBluez`and `openpyxl` in the PyCharm.

[Can't install time module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522650/cant-install-time-module) The answer to the `time` package is that `The time module is part of Python's standard library. It's installed along with the rest of Python, and you don't need to (nor can you!) install it with pip.`

The error warning info when I installed the `PyBluez` module is always the same as follows:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/Users/ringo/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/e7/40/9d/b772a3cf2ca121e87a06eabe9483271816581dec7c772272d3'

[image: error info screenshot for install PyBluez]

When it occurred,I changed to install it in the terminal app with the command `sudo pip3 install PyBluez`

**The error info:**
 **Failed building wheel for PyBluez**

> Command "/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-build-umoukn9i/PyBluez/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-53lcxusy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-umoukn9i/PyBluez/

**Install openpyxl:**
After I installed `openpyxl` in the terminal app with `sudo pip3 install openpyxl`,I re-open a PyCharm project,but the module isn't in the packege list.When I `import openpyxl` and run the project, the info `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`occurs.

If I install it with PyCharm,the error message is the same as that when install `PyBluez`
[image: no openpyxl]

**How to solve the issues?** It requires me to swipe before I can continue so it slows me down... I will be really grateful if you could share some right method that I should look into. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Add further infomation:**

[Cannot import Bluetooth in Python 3 (OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017374/cannot-import-bluetooth-in-python-3-osx)With this question asked by Carl Bratt,I found the answer:

> This is the closed OS X import issue #108 on GitHub:
>   http://github.com/karulis/pybluez/issues/108
>
> It's actually quite an old issue.
>
> One thing the author suggested you might do is remove your current
>   installation and install the GitHub repo using pip:

`git clone https://github.com/karulis/pybluez.git
pip install -e pybluez`

**Another command you can use:**

`pip3 install --upgrade git+https://github.com/rgov/pybluez.git#egg=pybluez`

Answer (score 0):

try to install anaconda3 instead of python itself
https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos
I'm using anaconda for python

Comment: Ok,thanks,I will go to learn what's anaconda3  and how to use it.

Comment: `The following packages are not available from current channels:- pybluez` It seems that anaconda doesn't support the package `PyBluez` that is used for Bluetooth programming.So maybe I still need to use PyCharm.